# Mountain Lion printer not found on bonjour, can't install by IP

Tags: macos, printing, bonjour

My networked HP6310 suddenly stopped working today from my MBPro running Mountain Lion. Other laptops in the house (MB running Snow Leopard, MBP running Lion) can still print. I can connect via USB and print, so I don't believe it's the driver. I deleted the networked printer, intending to reinstall, but found that the printer is not found by Bonjour. I can access the printer on the web using the IP address, but not by using the address HP4xxxxx.local. I tried adding the printer by IP, but got this:

[image: error msg]

Suggestions on how to resolve?

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution, although I'm unable to say why it works, or if I've lost something else in the process. A search on Bonjour/Actiontec/wireless yielded (http://yabfog.com/blog/2012/09/14/making-fios-actiontec-router-and-apple-bonjour-services-play-together) with the suggestion to disable IGMP proxy on the Actiontec router. No issues since I made the change.

Comment: It works because sometimes routers, bridges, and switches on a network start misbehaving. Disabling the IGMP proxy removes the choice from your router, essentially, and makes it always do the thing Bonjour needs it to do.